# Como pegar valor da URL

Tags: java

Me ajudem...

Estou travado na seguinte questão...

Preciso pegar o id do usuário que vem através do parametro da URL, conforme abaixo:

localhost:8080/sgc/pages/gerarSenha.xhtml?id=3

Mas não sei como pegar esse valor "id=3".

É enviado um link para o email do usuário que esqueceu a senha, então quando o usuário clica no link esse valor não existe mais no ManagedBean, aí onde estou travado. Como faço para pegar esse valor?

Me ajudem, por favor.

Comment: o teu form está com uma requisição get?

Comment: Poderia mostrar como está fazendo no momento? Fica mais fácil para ajudar!

Comment: Qual a linguagem esta utilizando no servidor? PHP?

Comment: Galera, estou usando via GET. Mas conseguir resolver o problema, usando um metodo que recupera o valor por parametro, mas o problema fundamental era devido está usando a anotacao "ViewScoped" e o certo seria "SessionScoped" devido destruir as informações contida na bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa usar um cara chamado ViewParam é um metadado que adicionado à sua página te permite capturar este tipo de informação passada por parametro.
Primefaces - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/push/viewparam.jsf?data=Pushed

ViewParam é da especificação jsf o exemplo da utilização com primefaces é didática mas funciona da mesma forma com qualquer outra biblioteca, se estiver usando uma.

Comment: Tentei usar por f:param mas não consegui... Mas obrigado pela ajuda!